# @table in FROM clause

Tags: sql, database, oracle

My manager (not currently working in an IT environment) sent me a chunk of code to run some data however one line confuses me. For some context, this is ORACLE SQL.

She has a line set as "FROM ma1 @proddb m1"

I'm not currently sure what it does or even trying to achieve. It's hard for me to visualize it since I do not have access to the database itself.

What's the proper syntax for that line as that's where I'm currently getting errors. Thank you!

Comment: [This might be useful?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36339812/266304). What error are you getting? (Probably not surprising that you get an error if you don't have access to the database, but...)

Comment: Yes, and correctly formatted it would be "... from ma1@proddb m1...". There should be no space between the table name and the database link designation. This will only work if there is a working database link named "proddb" already defined in the database schema you are accessing.

Answer (score 2):

> What's the proper syntax for that line as that's where I'm currently getting errors.

`@` indicates a [database link](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/ds_concepts002.htm#ADMIN12086)

The [syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_10002.htm#i2126073) is:

> [image]

```sql
FROM table_name@dblink table_alias
```

So for you:

- `ma1` is the name of the table/view/materialized view.
- `proddb` is the name of the database link.
- `m1` is the table alias.

The only thing that is wrong with your syntax is that you need to remove the space character between `ma1` and `@proddb`. If you do that then it should work assuming that the database link and the remote table/view/materialized view exist.

Answer (score 0):

"FROM ma1@proddb m1" -> ma1 is a table from a different DB, with @my_remote_DB you have access to objects on a remote database. In your case proddb is your remote database link.